# Is there any way to force apps to use internal memory only on rooted Android device?

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, magisk, oneplus-5t

I have OnePlus 5T 8GB RAM + 128GB internal storage. 100GB free space is available on phone. I rooted the device.

Now, I am facing a problem regarding installing apps from Google Play Store. When I try to install any random app, it's showing

> **App Requires External Storage**
>
> [app name] can't be downloaded. Insert an [SD card](https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6088895?hl=en) or USB storage with sufficient storage, and try again.

And also no apps are using Internal Storage for storing the data like Camera, WhatsApp, etc. I am even not able to download and see the WhatsApp images or any document shared and not able to download anything from Chrome too.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The support link is dead and additionally it contains the term `android-one`. Are you sure you only rooted the device and not installed a different customROM on it? If you are running a customROM then I would assume that this is just a bug of the ROM especially as it happens on "any random app".

Comment: no Sir I haven't Installed CustomRom . I used ADB , UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.82-20170528234214 ,twrp-3.4.0-10-cheeseburger-dumpling-mauronofrio.img

Comment: The wording *"External Storage"* in context of android apps actually means Internal Storage */storage/emulated/0* maybe the symlink */sdcard* is missing. at least it's a bit strange you tagged question Magisk but in comments it's about SuperSU

Comment: Similar issue on XDA Forum: [Unable to install/update apps to internal storage](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unable-to-install-update-apps-to-internal-storage.4139859/)